# Get YouTube ID from youtube embed url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I want to get only youtube id from the following url

https://www.youtube.com/embed/cqyziA30whE?controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=0&loop=0

```
 $(".youtube").click(function () {
       console.log(this.href.replace(new RegExp("embed\\/", "i"), 'embed/'));

 });
```

This gets me the whole url while i want to get only YouTubeID  `cqyziA30whE` when ever user click on any of the links

Comment: I closed this question as a dupe of a famous old one. If that didn't answer your question please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegEx [groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and capture it.

```js
var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/nrGk0AuFd_9?controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=0&loop=0';
console.log(url.replace(new RegExp("^.*\/embed\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\?.*", "i"), '$1'));
```

Comment: You are validating it for only basic characters what if it has other characters? Example `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrGk0AuFd_9` this has `_`

Comment: @Learning Well you could just add the characters `-` and `_` to the regex. YouTube video id's allows only these characters other than `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. So final `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`.

Answer (score 2):

Capture non-question mark characters following `/embed/` in a group, then use that captured group:

```js
const str = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/cqyziA30whE?controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=0&loop=0';
console.log(
  str.match(/\/embed\/([^?]+)/)[1]
);
```

You could also lazy-repeat any character until you get to a question mark:

```js
const str = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/cqyziA30whE?controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=0&loop=0';
console.log(
  str.match(/\/embed\/(.+)\?/)[1]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Split()` the string with `\` separator and then [split()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-string-prototype-split-function/) the result with seperator `?` and the desired result is the first element of splitted array..

```js
var string = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/cqyziA30whE?controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=0&loop=0";
var words=string.split('/');
console.log(words[4].split('?')[0]);
```

Comment: *This might help you.* is never a good answer text. Instead explain your approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a smart way to avoid `RegExp` you can use [`HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname) like this:

```js
const href = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/cqyziA30whE?controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=0&loop=0'
const a = document.createElement('a')

a.href = href

const id = a.pathname.split('/').pop()

console.log(id)
```

Based on your snippet you might be able to do something as simple as this:

```
$(".youtube").click(function() {
  console.log(this.pathname.split('/').pop());
});
```